# GPGME: how to check if we can decrypt a secret and own a matching key?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, gpgme

With [GPGME](https://www.gnupg.org/software/gpgme/index.html), how would I check if I can decrypt a given secret with the current keychain.

I can attempt decryption with [`gpgme_op_decrypt`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Decrypt.html#index-gpgme_005fop_005fdecrypt) and catch [`GPG_ERR_NO_SECKEY`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Error-Codes.html#index-error-codes_002c-list-of-1) errors, but this seems non-optimal, nor do I know if this covers all cases.

Is there `can_decrypt` function, `do_we_own_decrypt_key_for_secret` or alike?

Also, can I list the secret recipients without decrypting the secret, that could help with this issue.